# Yii2 выполнение JS-сценария при ошибке ajax-валидации

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация

Есть форма:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'user-create-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
  'enableClientValidation' => false,
  'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(Yii::$app->controller->id . '/validation'),
  'validateOnType' => true,
]);
```

К форме подключен js-скрипт, который выполняет транслитерацию русских букв, согласно правилу, при наборе их в соответствующих полях (событие `.keyup()`) и добавляет полученный результат в поле `samname`.

Есть правило валидации в модели `UserCreateForm`:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    [['samname'], 'validateUserExist'],
  ];
}

public function validateUserExist()
{
    $check = Yii::$app->CustomComponents->checkUserExist($this->samname);
    if ($check) {
       $errorMessage = 'Найден: ' . $check;
       $this->addError('samname', $errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Функция `checkUserExist()` проверяет существование созданного имени и в случае нахождения возвращает результат.

И action в контроллере:

```
public function actionValidation()
{
    $model = new UserCreateForm();

    if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validate($model));
        \Yii::$app->end();
    }
}
```

И все прекрасно работает - валидация выполняется, в случае нахождения имени возвращается ошибка.

Но!

Мне необходимо, чтобы при возвращении ошибки снова выполнялся скрипт и добавлял к имени еще одну букву (такой функционал в нем заложен). Как это можно реализовать?

Как выполнить скрипт при возвращении ошибки валидатором и снова запустить проверку?

Answer (score 3):

Решение: использовать событие 'afterValidateAttribute'.

```
    $('form').on('afterValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, message) {
        if (attribute.name === 'samname')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "url-to-action",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    if ( typeof(response["form-samname"]) != "undefined" && response["form-samname"] !== null ) {
                        // code here
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Источник: https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/